# How to programatically select all text inside a TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, jeditable

I'm looking for a way to programatically select all the content inside a TinyMCE editor instance.

The reason I need this is that I'd like it if all the text inside the editor was selected, as soon as someone clicks on it (I'm using TinyMCE in conjunction with JEditable, by the way).

Thanks,
Edan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have your TinyMCE editor instance stored in a variable called `ed`:

```
ed.selection.select(ed.getBody(), true);
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up adding a setup function in the tineMCE.init() settings, which did exactly this.

Comment: @Tim Down what does ed stand for ?? how should i initialize

Answer (score 1):

For tinyMCE 4 I'm using the Range Object for selection:

```js
function selectAll(editor) {
    range = editor.dom.createRng();
    range.selectNodeContents(editor.getBody());
    editor.selection.setRng(range);
}

selectAll(tinyMCE.focusedEditor);
```